# Is [number, number] a tuple type?

Tags: arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6, tuples, destructuring

In the below code,

```
function f([first, second]: [number, number]){
    console.log(first);
    console.log(second);
}

var input:number[] = [1,2];
f(input);
```

`number[]` type variable(`input`) is passed to `f`.

Why compiler errors out? `Argument of type 'number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[number, number]'.
  Type 'number[]' is missing the following properties from type '[number, number]': 0, 1ts(2345)`

Comment: What else would `[1, 2]` be, other than `[number, number]`?

Comment: @Cerbrus Can't it be `number[]`? We did this in C, Java...

Comment: @Cerbrus A `number[]` array apparently

Comment: The question is "Why does this compile/typecheck?", not "How does this work?", right?

Comment: `[number, number]` (array of two members that are numbers) is more specific than `number[]` (array of *x* members that are numbers), that is why TypeScript will throw a compilation error. If you reverse the type declaration and use `var input: [number, number]` and `f([first, second]: number[])` it will work.

Comment: @Bergi `f(input)` does not compile. `f([1, 2])` compiles. I know, why it compiles.

Comment: @overexchange As stated, your code is defining `input` specifically as an array of numbers of any length, while the function only accepts an array of 2 numbers.

Comment: @Bergi This tuple type in TypeScript with square brackets is confusing me unlike python tuples. I think you answered my question

Comment: @Terry function `f` does not accept array(`number[]`) type

Comment: @overexchange Of course not, as `[number, number]` is not `number[]`. This is *not* a tuple type! It simply means an array of two elements that are of type `number`. This is akin to passing a variable of type `any` into a function that accepts `string`.

Comment: @Terry you said: *function only accepts an array of 2 numbers*, which is not the case. it accepts tuple type `[number, number]`

Comment: @overexchange No I didn't not say that, you're taking it out of context--reread my entire comment. What I meant is the function only accepts an array of 2 numbers, but you are providing an array of unknown length of numbers. Of course it will reject it.

Comment: @Bergi Below answer looks wrong to me. How can we avoid votes for confusion?

Comment: @overexchange You can [edit] your question to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Bergi Edited the question, as you suggested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript can be very specific in what it expects to be passed to a method.

For your example:

```
function f([first, second]: [number, number]){
    console.log(first);
    console.log(second);
}
```

This will work:

```
var x: [number, number] = [1,2];

f([1,2]); // Type is implied:  [number, number]
f(x);     // Type is explicit: [number, number]
```

This won't:

```
var x = [1,2,3];
var y = [1,2];
var z: number[] = [1,2];

f(x); // Type is implied:  number[]
f(y); // Type is implied:  number[]
f(z); // Type is explicit: number[]
```

You told typescript to *expect* an array containing 2 numbers. That's why it won't accept *anything* but an array containing 2 numbers.

You can change the accepted type like this:

```
function f([first, second]: number[]){
// Keep destructuring ^,      ^ but change the accepted type.
    console.log(first);  
    console.log(second);
}
```

Then, any of the previous 6 examples will work, as `[number, <number...>]` are also `number[]` arrays.

Comment: Your answer looks incorrect to me. For `let inp = [1, 2];` compiler's type inference says `inp` as  `number[]`

Comment: @overexchange: You just ___completely___ broke my answer. You're making a lot of incorrect _assumptions_ about how TypeScript works.

Comment: `f(x)` will not work, where `var x = [1,2]` because `x` is inferred as `number[]` type

Comment: I missed that one.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about arrays but simple type checking. 
It gives you an error, because type `number[]` is not same as `[number, number]`.

You can change `input` type to `[number, number]` as follows

`var input: [number, number] = [1, 2]`

or keep the input as is and do following

`f(input as [number, number])`

**Edit**

`f([1,2])` works just fine because you are explicitly passing two numbers.

Comment: Updated my answer